# How secure is a 100-bit password in 2018 and onwards?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, file-encryption

Long story short, I share a server with a few other people and store my backups there. All these backups are archived to a .7z file using AES-256 encryption, using a randomly-generated password of about 100 bits of entropy. Assuming my backups became public, how hard would it be to access their contents in 2018 and beyond?

Comment: How far you want? Bitcoin mining reached 2^91 hashes this year. Summit can reach 2^63 in one hour. Quantum computer reduces sqrt(2^256)=2^128 immediately.

Comment: @kelalaka AES-256 is encryption, not a hashing function. OP, this post might interest you: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46559/what-are-the-chances-that-aes-256-encryption-is-cracked

Comment: @Ian I've given only for comparison. The real numbers will be only a ratios SHA-1 vs AES-256 speed. This might more interest https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't believe it's relevant. More relevant is the advice in the linked question over at crypto.stackexchange where the accepted answer discusses threat modelling.

Comment: in the end, the attacker will try to find the passphrase if nothing else included in the key generation. It is easier than to break the full AES-256 keys.

Comment: in short, that should be enough for the rest of your life, barring some miracle breakthrough.

Comment: @kelalaka Keep in mind that these figures are for _hashes_ not for _password hashes_ which are a completely different thing despite the confusingly similar name. What matters most for this question is how 7z hardens the password. I remember from a previous question on this site that zip does it properly (excluding some antique versions). I don't know about 7z, I would hope that it does but I can't state this as a fact.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I've found [this](http://www.crark.net/crark-7zip.html) `At least from version 3.x, 7-Zip has been using a strong AES algorithm, which doesn't allow any attacks more effective than the brute force. Besides, the key derivation function is very similar to RAR one, and uses more than 130000 SHA-256 transformations and brute force rate on modern CPU is very low, only several hundreds of passwords per second. This carries inference that 7-Zip password encryption is one of the strongest between popular encryption systems in the context of brute force rate. `

Answer (score 1):

All of the comments assume a brute force attack against the encrypted file.  In cryptography, however, this is far from the only attack to consider.

As an example, AES-256 is generally considered 'computationally secure' by modern standards but there a lot of assumptions in just saying that. Computationally secure means that while it's secure by modern standards, history has proven it won't always be secure. 
 AES operates in different modes (CBC, ECB, CFB, OFB, CTS) -- each with their own targeted attacks against each mode.

As an example in Cipher Block Chaining, after the first round, the cipher text from the previous round is xor'd with the plaintext in the current block but circling back to the first round, the encryptor must be provided the first bits of randomness (called the Initialization Vector or IV).  If this isn't done properly, this can be used to systematically derive the ciphertext that's xor'd in all for each subsequent blocks and thus, providing the unCBC'd ciphertext that can be statistically analyzed or brute forced to derive the key.

Additionally, your password can be targeted.  You already leaked some interesting information about it.

- You said it was randomly generated with 100-bits of entropy and
  around 20 chars.  With that, I can roughly derive the keyspace and
  probably make an educated guess as to the randomness (uppers, lowers,
  numbers, and a handful of common specials).
- You said it was randomly generated... was it cryptographically randomly generated or did it use a pseudo-random number generator?  Most PRNGs have significant weakness (e.g. based on atomic clock values) -- so if I know when the file was created, file metadata or in the filename itself, I might be able derive the seed and generate the same value you did at that time, thus significantly limiting the effectiveness of the 'randomness' almost to the point of negating it.
- You said it was a passphrase, and not a password.  This also leaks information.  If true, it means your password probably isn't really cryptographically secure (e.g. 1r5%vb9*?_ad!@KLvnd) and probably something closer to I<3G0ldenR3tri3v3rs!!.  L337 speak is not cryptographically secure and good cracker will have dictionary files with common l337 speak variations on common words to significantly lower the time to crack.

So... to answer your question on **how hard would it be to access their contents in 2018 and beyond?** -- *it highly depends on a number of factors*.

Comment: "the encryptor must be provided the first bits of randomness (called the Initialization Vector or IV). If this isn't done properly, this can be used to systematically derive the IVs for each subsequent block and thus, elluding to the initally supplied randomness (e.g. password/passphrase/etc.)" - It's a bit hard to tell, but are you actually claiming that a predictable IV would both completely break confidentiality _and_ reveal the key used?

Comment: "You said it was randomly generated with 100-bits of entropy and around 20 chars. With that, I can roughly derive the keyspace and probably make an educated guess as to the randomness (uppers, lowers, numbers, and a handful of common specials)." - 100 bits in 20 characters is 5 bits per character, which means a character space of 32. Your educated guess of uppercase, lowercase, digits, and special characters makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald, first comment:  no, in CBC, only the first block in interesting for cryptanalysis because of how CBC works with using previous blocks on each subsequent round.  But if the IV can be derived, then the an attacker can remove the CBC additional protections and just get to the ciphertext of just the password.

Comment: "this can be used to systematically derive the IVs" is what is confusing me, by definition the IV is only used for the _initial_ block. For CBC sometimes people call block `n` the "IV" for block `n+1` since it's what is xored with it, but that doesn't make sense either because there's no need to "derive" them, you already have them because they literally _are_ the ciphertext.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald, second comment:  confusing maybe and I may misunderstand his meaning but 100 bits of entropy should refer to the amount of randomness or diversity in the possible random selections of character values--meaning 26+26+10+, ~48 specials, assuming english language password.  '~' because he said around 20 characters, not specifically 20.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald - for seed/salt, I was thinking about IVs and misspoke with salt/versus seed -- thanks.

Comment: 100 bits of entropy means the entire password has 100 bits of entropy, not that there are 100 characters in the character space. If there are (approximately) 20 characters, then the number of possible passwords is [size of character space]^20, for 100 bits of entropy (meaning 2^100 possible passwords) you need a character space of exactly 32 characters. This could be lowercase characters and a few digits, a combination of lowercase and uppercase, or anything else, it doesn't really matter. All you can really conclude is that the character space _must_ have at least 32 characters in it.

Comment: Not all of what I said is true :P

I was only worried about my actual key being the weakest link in the chain, and reading your answer, I can assure myself that it isn't.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald,  You are right on entropy.  Most passwords I've used to are around 132-133 bits of entropy.  I was thinking 100 bits (without doing the math) would at least 26 upper and lower and 10 numbers and a handful of specials -- I should done the math. Powershell:  [math]::Log([math]::Pow(32, 20), 2) = 100.  So that character space doesn't really make sense to me as I've always found it assumable for at least uppers/lowers/numbers/and 2 or more specials.

Comment: Btw... The Beast Attack is an example of using an IV to unwrap the remaining CBC'd mode to attack the remaining cipher text.

Comment: @thepip3r Ah, I see what you're saying there. When you say that "ciphertext that can be statistically analyzed or brute forced to derive the key" though it sounds like a roundabout way of saying "AES could be broken or your 100 bit key could be brute forced", both of which are not currently known to be possible.

Comment: As far as predictable IV, yes that's an issue, but it only breaks confidentiality if there's an encryption oracle and you can guess the ciphertext (BEAST improves this by using chosen plaintext to guess 1 byte at a time), but I don't think there's an encryption oracle here. If you're just trying to point out that there can be subtle weaknesses though, no problem :)

Comment: This answer is mostly irrelevant. CBC has weaknesses, but do they apply to 7z encryption? The discussion of password structure is not relevant except to question the assertion that the password actually has 100 bits of entropy. A statement like “the password is generated with 100 bits of entropy” assumes that the attacker knows the structure. Either the statement is correct, and the discussion of the password structure is irrelevant, or the statement is not correct. The crucial thing for security here is what 7z does to harden the password.

Comment: The post was talking about different ways weaknesses could be exposed either in the password or the difference facets of the encryption itself and how those weaknesses, relative to modern cryptoanalysis leave his file in the long term--CBC was just an example of how different modes of encryption can be attacked.    If the answer is so irrelevant, you're always welcome to post an answer so we can critique yours.

Comment: He doesn't provide the order of operations.  Is the archiving process also doing the encryption?  ...Or are they paired operations (archive -> encrypt).  If it's the former, then how his password was generated matters (ie. discussion on entropy, keyspace, and character space)--if it's the latter, then we have no details on the encrypt process (OpenSSL libs or other).  Assuming an attacker doens't know the details if they're being offered up as they did in the post, isn't legit either.  Most don't just happen upon a trove of encrypted files.  If they're in the net, they can read emails and txts